# Proving continuity of $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to prove the continuity for:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2$$
What I've got so far:
$$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |x^2-x_0^2|<\epsilon$$
$$|x^2-x_0^2|=|x+x_0||x-x_0|<|x+x_0|\delta=|x-x_0+2x_0|\delta\leq(|x-x_0|+|2x_0|)\delta=(\delta+|2x_0|)\delta$$
but how do I continue, I am stuck here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $\delta = \min (\frac {\epsilon}{|2x_0| + 1},1)$

Comment: @DougM I'd appreciate it, if you could elaborate, how the $\delta$ disappears, and where the $1$ comes from, maybe I could understand then why we use the $min$ here

Comment: In this case using "min" is not really necessary.  But it is a common enough technique that it is wroth knowing.  You need to show that a $\delta$ exists for a given $\epsilon.$   Rarely is there need to find the largest possible delta.  Since we expect $\delta$ to be small, sometimes it is easier if we establish an upper bound.  If we say that $\delta \le 1$ then  $\delta^2\le 1$ which will allow us to replace $\delta^2$ with $1$ and the inequality will still be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you now had $(\delta+2x_0)\delta = \epsilon$, you'd be done. Since you are free to choose $\delta$ based on $x_0$ and $\epsilon$, manipulate this equation so it gives you a choice for $\delta$.

Comment: that's the point I am struggling at, probably because of my lack in inequalities

Comment: @user3125470 We can always choose a smaller $\delta$ than we need to, so we can assume $\delta <1$, so $\delta^2 < \delta$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, explains everything now. Thanks